# Join with a max and nulls

Tags: sql-server, subquery, max, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables:

```
People:
ID |  Name
----------
1  | John
2  | David
3  | Jennifer
```

another which is has a simple FK to the first

```
Note:
ID | People_ID | Note
----------------------
1  |  1        | A note
2  |  1        | Another note
3  |  3        | Jen's note
```

I want to get the note associated with the `max(ID)` from Note for each person, or a null if no notes, so the desired result is:

```
People_ID | Name   | Note
----------------------------
1         |John    | Another Note
2         |David   | NULL
3         |Jennifer| Jen's Note
```

I can perform a join, but can't include David because the max criteria doesn't bring back the null column. Any help please?

Comment: Left join and row_number, partition by id, order by noteId. Select just 1 row. Ms docs have good description and examples of [row_number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Sorry, can I alter the question (I know, bad form) - instead of the MaxNoteID in the result, I want the note itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a `left join` - and I would recommend pre-aggregating the notes in a subquery:

```
select p.*, n.*
from people p
left join (
    select people_id, max(id) max_note_id
    from note
    group by people_id
) n on n.people_id = p.id
```

There are situations where a lateral join would be more efficient:

```
select p.*, n.*
from people p
outer apply (
    select top(1) id max_note_id 
    from note n 
    where n.people_id = p.id
    order by id desc
) n
```

The nice thing about the lateral join is that you can easily bring more columns from the top matching record in the `note` table if you want to (like the text of the note, or else).

Comment: Thanks for the effort and apologies, I really want the actual note out - have altered the initial question

Comment: @GreigM: I was suspecting that. Use the lateral join solution; you just need to change `select top(1)` id as max_note_id ...` to `select top(1) * ...`, and you get the entire corresponding row from the note table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query:

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0fe96/6)

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.ID, MAX(B.ID)  FROM PEOPLE A LEFT OUTER JOIN NOTE B
ON (A.ID = B.PEOPLE_ID) GROUP BY A.NAME, A.ID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort and apologies, I really want the actual note out - have altered the initial question.  I haven't used sqlfiddle before, very useful